# Are there any benefits of parsing an SVG as either XML or HTML when I won't inject into any document?

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a serialized svg:

```
const svg = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
</svg>`
```

Using jquery I can parse it into either HTML or XML:

```
const doc = $.parseXML(serializedSvg);
const nodes = $.parseHTML(serializedSvg);
```

Is there any advantage of using either method over the other?

I won't inject the svg into any document.

Differences that I can imagine but don't know about, and would want to learn more about from someone who knows:

- Either method allows a somewhat different syntax
- Either format makes more methods available

Comment: Assuming you mean $.parseHTML - then use the one that gives you what you need - what *do* you need to do with the parsed SVG?  SVG *is* XML, so I'd go with `$.parseXML`

Comment: @freedomn-m: oops, edited